# Importing local modules into Snakemake files

Tags: python, snakemake

How do you import local files (.py files) into Snakemake files (.smk files)? I have the following example structure:

```
parent_dir
├── dir1
│   └── a.py
└── dir2
    └── b.smk
```

I would like to import `a.py` into `b.smk`. I tried the following:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.parent)
import dir1.a
```

but had no success. It results in a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Is there a way around this? I do **not** want to change the extension of `a.py` to `.smk`.

Comment: Importing a module into a Snakefile shouldn't be all too different from importing a module into a regular python file - do any of the answers to this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: It's not the same though because the reason why there is a `ModuleNotFoundError` is because when you run snakemake, the path of `__file__` is not the path to `b.smk`. It is the path to `workflow.py` which is an internal Snakemake file. Try it for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, `__file__` gives the path to the snakemake module workflow.py. You can access the path to the snakefile with `workflow.basedir` (I think there is a better method though, check the documentation). Also, I think you need to convert the Path object to string. So something like:

```
sys.path.insert(0, Path(workflow.basedir).parent.as_posix())
print(sys.path) # for debugging

import dir1.a

rule all:
    input:
        ...
```

then inside directory `dir2` execute: `snakemake -s b.smk -j 1 ...`

---

Edit: I think `workflow.basedir` is a bit of a hack; in fact, it is not even documented. Better would be to look at [accessing auxiliary files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#accessing-auxiliary-source-files)

Comment: Oh yes I completely forgot about `workflow.basedir`. Thanks!

Comment: See edit about a better way although I use `workflow.basedir` all the time myself!